# Why does it take so long for my thread to exit when it's finished?

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, task-parallel-library

I have an issue (maybe it's not an issue) where I create a thread, it does it's work, then I finish and the working thread (that I created the task with) is exited.  In my mind I see everything being completed and the new thread I created should have exited.  But for some reason the thread does NOT actually exit for a few more seconds (about 5-8 seconds) after the function has completed.  I can tell by watching the output window for lines like...

> The thread 'threadTaskWorker16' (0xdd8c) has exited with code 0 (0x0).

Here is how I create the new thread...

```
public bool CreateNewTask()
{
    Task<TaskInfo> taskWork = Task.Factory
        .StartNew(() => threadTaskWorker(taskParams),
        CancellationToken.None,
        TaskCreationOptions.None,
        TaskScheduler.Default)
        .ContinueWith(task => threadTaskComplete(task.Result));
}

private TaskInfo threadTaskWorker(TaskInfo taskParams)
{
    Thread.CurrentThread.Name = "threadTaskWorker" + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
    Debug.WriteLine("Thread " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId + " has started it's long and exhausting process that would have hung the GUI out to dry...");
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(3000);
    }
    Debug.WriteLine("Thread has completed it's work.");
}

private TaskInfo threadTaskComplete(TaskInfo taskParams)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Thread " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId + " has been destroyed.");
}
```

So my question is, why does it take so long to actually EXIT the thread after the custom function has completed?  I was thinking about somehow killing the thread at the end of my function but that seems like I would be going about it the wrong way.  Is there a way to make the thread exit sooner?

Second question, Is there a way to fire an event so I know when the thread actually exits (like when I see it in the output window)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are seeing the effect of the `ThreadPool`.  Since creating new threads is computationally expensive, Tasks will keep a "pool" of threads around and reuse them for multiple tasks if they are not in use.  Only after the Pool sees that it has extra unused threads will it actually physically kill the thread, showing that message in the output window.

Your `threadTaskDestroyed` should be getting called as soon as the task completes, no need for any kind of event.  If you really want more controll, look at some of the synchronization objects like `Mutex` or `AutoResetEvent`.  If you are using Tasks you shouldn't have to worry about managing threads though, it's all handled for you and "does the right thing" in the majority of the cases.

See this MSDN article for more information https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ka9477y(v=vs.110).aspx

BTW, **NEVER** kill a thread. You will leave things in a VERY unpredictable state. http://www.interact-sw.co.uk/iangblog/2004/11/12/cancellation

Comment: Good answer!  That's what I was thinking, when developing I don't usually like "loose ends" (in this case letting the threadpool be handled for me)...  My functions get called just fine (both of them) but seeing a lingering "The thread blah has exited" pop into the debugger just itched my "got to be in control" tendency.  So it seems like I'll be leaving it just the way I have it then!  Now that I know it wasn't something I was doing wrong.  :)  Thanks!